# Change number of decimal digits for features in ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system, point, vertices, decimal-points

I am editing vertices in polygons and points in ArcMap 10, and realised that they only hold 3 decimal digits for the X, Y coordinates, but I would like at least 6 decimal digits. Even if I type in more digits, it gets rounded up to 3. How do I change this? Thanks.

Comment: file geodatabase? personal geodatabase or shapefile which format are you using? - you will need to recreate geodb with the precision - http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Migrating_to_high_precision/003n00000033000000/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To display more, go to editor -> options -> general tab in Arc 10.

Answer (score 4):

1. In ArcMap, open the Attribute Table of the feature class in question.
2. Go to the field properties by right-clicking the column heading of the fields in question (one at a time) and selecting Properties
3. Click the box that looks like this [...] next to Numeric and set the rounding.

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't actually round. It just displays that way.

Answer (score 1):

May be the problem has already been solved. I was facing the same problem and today I fixed it in this way
Customize--ArcMap options---Data view---round coordinates to (select from drop down).I put 6 and that worked.